# Find the fallacy or fallacies in the argument

Tags: logic

I'm almost sure that there is no fallacy in the argument, but I'm going to ask it anyway.

Question;

Find the fallacy or fallacies in the argument

> The cow moos whenever the pig oinks.The cow moos.Therefore, the pig oinks.

it means symbolically,

P: The cow moos

Q: The pig oinks

$$ (P \rightarrow Q) \wedge P \Rightarrow Q $$

So, where is the fallacy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $P$ denoting "The cow moos" and $Q$ denoting "The pig oinks",

> The cow moos whenever the pig oinks

is $Q \to P$, not $P \to Q$.

Comment: you are right, thanks.